# Run git commands with .bashrc from windows command line

Tags: git, command-line, git-bash

I am trying to execute a git pull from inside a batch file but from what I see you have to run this http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-06/msg00537.html script in your .bashrc to get the ssh-agent running.

Is there another way to execute a git pull using certificates from the windows command line or is there a way to run the git commands and make them get executed after the .bashrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one way of doing this is adding the git bin folder to your path and running sh.exe --login bashPullScript.sh